# Ejs cambia la fecha en la vista

Tags: javascript, nodejs, javascript-objeto, ejs

Tengo un objeto con la consulta de mongo y me trae la fecha de creación del documento. si imprimo el objeto la fecha esta bien. pero cuando imprimo solo el campo la hora tiene -5 horas de la zona horaria y no he podido encontrar un metodo para que se imprima el campo sin modificar. Gracias

[image: Objeto con el campo]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para este ejemplo la fecha del registro fue a las 15:27 y cuando la imprimo aparece 10:27.

Comment: Toma en cuenta que MongoDB almacena la fecha en UTC, por lo tanto, si se guarda a las 10:27 con zona horaria -05:00, se guardará en MongoDB con hora 15:27 UTC. Lo que debes hacer es asegurarte de que la fecha que envías y la que recibes siempre se procesen bajo la misma zona horaria. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema no se debe a `EJS`, sino a la zona horaria donde es ejecuta el `Javascript`.

Para poder imprimir la fecha, `Javascript` convierte un objeto `Date` a una cadena, para lo cual automáticamente se llama al método [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

Dicho método **toma la zona horaria del cliente que lo ejecuta** (*servidor o navegador*).

```js
let date = new Date('2021-03-11T15:27:50.803Z');
console.log(date + '');
console.log(date.toString());
```

---

#### Solución:

Podes utilizar el método [`toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) el cual convierte una fecha en una cadena, utilizando la zona horaria `UTC`

```js
let date = new Date('2021-03-11T15:27:50.803Z');
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio ya la fecha quedo perfecta.